# Making nuget work when its referenced in multiple solutions or by itself?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

We have the following project structure in a solution:

> .\Project2
>    .\Project1

Project2 is dependent on Project1. Project1 is shared across multiple projects. I added the nuget packages (Roslyn for example) for Project1 when it was part of this solution. The problem we are having if either we try to compile Project1 by itself or compile it when its in an entirely another app it fails:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ../../Project2/packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.
```

If i open the project file in a text editor it has the following statments in the project file:

```
<Import Project="..\..\Project2\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.2.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\Secured Account Access\Member\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.2.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

If of course removed all the nuget references and then just opened the individual project and added the nuget references. Which fixed when i was trying to compile the project by itself and broke it when it was part of the solution because VS will no longer restore the packages for Project1 while its in the solution.

I'm not sure why VS/Nuget works this way. Why not always have a package folder for each project? Disk Space savings (which would be absolutely nothing)? You should never have references that look like the following:

```
../../Project2/Packages/MyNugetDepedency.dll
```

Is there any way to get around this and have everything just work.

Comment: I don't think you'll want to reference Project1 via NuGet; reference it via a normal Project Reference.

Comment: @andy. I need to make it a little clearer i guess. I'm not referencing Project1 via nuget. Its a project reference. I'm only referencing nuget packages on nuget.org like roslyn for example

Comment: Oh I see; looks like you need an SLN file in the parent directory to both project1 and 2, which should then have packages at the same level as your project1/2 folders.

Answer (score 2):

The packages folder is determined by the solution the project is contained in by default. You can override the default packages directory by specifying the [repositoryPath](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings#repository-path) in a NuGet.Config file.

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="../MyPackages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

To have multiple solutions all share the same packages directory you can create a NuGet.Config file, with a repositoryPath setting, in a directory that is a parent to all the solutions. NuGet will then work its way up each directory until it finds a NuGet.Config file and then use the repositoryPath defined there. This repositoryPath is relative to the NuGet.Config file itself, unless you have specified a full path. A relative path is probably what you want so other developers do not need to check out the source code to the same directory.